# Interesting Probability

Tags: probability

If you throw a coin 10 times and each time you get the (number)side, what are the chances for you to get the (number) side again for the eleventh time?
Consider that for each through, the laws of probability tend to equalize the two possible chances.

Comment: Have you thought about the problem so far? We're not here to just do your homework. Not sure what you mean about "(number) side", but in general, provided that each flip is independent of the previous ones, do you think the result of the first 10 would affect the last one? In other words, if I flipped 10 heads in a row on a regular coin, would the next flip still have a $50$% chance of being heads, or would this change?

Comment: What does it mean? "If you throw a coin 10 times and each time you get the (number)side"

Comment: Also, the title of the question... "*Interesting Probability*"... is a severe case of misnomer.  This is not interesting in the slightest.  The tags originally used were almost entirely irrelevant as well.

Comment: Does a coin remember what has happened to it the last ten throws? What do you think yourself?

Comment: Stats said yes.

Comment: 95.5%yes 4.5%no

Answer (score 0):

The probability remains the same as the previous flips.